# Failed to fetch AWS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, aws-sdk, react-tsx

I have a problem uploading files to the S3 bucket using the @aws-sdk/client-s3 library using PutObjectCommand and @aws-sdk/lib-storage Uploading files above 70kbps more or less returns the error:

```
`TypeError: Failed to fetch
  at FetchHttpHandler.handle (fetch-http-handler.js:56:13)
  at PutObjectCommand.js:56:58
  at flexibleChecksumsResponseMiddleware.js:17:26
  at deserializerMiddleware.js:2:32
  at check-content-length-header.js:18:16
  at awsAuthMiddleware.js:10:26
  at async retryMiddleware.js:24:46
  at async flexibleChecksumsMiddleware.js:54:20
  at async loggerMiddleware.js:3:26
  at async Promise.all (index 0)
upload.ts:31`
```

however files below that will normally

Functions that are used to upload files

`    import { PutObjectCommand, S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { Upload } from "@aws-sdk/lib-storage";
import { FetchHttpHandler } from "@smithy/fetch-http-handler";

```
const secretAccessKey = import.meta.env.VITE_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;
const accessKeyId = import.meta.env.VITE_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID;
const region = import.meta.env.VITE_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION;
const bucket = import.meta.env.VITE_BUCKET_NAME;

const client = new S3Client({
 credentials: { secretAccessKey, accessKeyId },
 region,
 requestHandler: new FetchHttpHandler({
  requestTimeout: 5000
 })
});

export const onUploadFiles = async (file: any) => {
 const upload = new Upload({
  client,
  params: {
   Bucket: bucket,
   Key: file.name,
   Body: file.file,
   ACL: "public-read"
  },
  partSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024
 });
 try {
  upload.on("httpUploadProgress", (progress) => {
   console.log(progress);
  });

  await upload.done();
 } catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
 }
};

export const onUpload = async (file: any, callback: (data: any) => void) => {
 const input = {
  Bucket: bucket,
  Key: file.name,
  Body: file.file,
  ACL: "public-read"
 };
 try {
  const response = await client.send(new PutObjectCommand(input));
  callback(response);
 } catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
 }
};`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem today. Attempting to upload any file (regardless of its size) using `client-s3` and `PutObjectCommand` resulted into `"TypeError: Failed to fetch"` message. What helped me was downgrading the `aws-sdk/client-s3` package to version `3.317.0`:

> npm remove --purge @aws-sdk/client-s3

> npm i @aws-sdk/client-s3@3.317.0

After that, upload to S3 worked again.  I hope this helps anyone facing a similar issue.

Comment: Thanks Marina! I've had this issue for 2 days and your solution fixed it!

Comment: Thank you, I downgraded too much but I didn't go that deep, it was resolved here too!

Answer (score -1):

try to upload with these params while upload object :
**Bucket,Key,ACL,Body,ContentLength,ContentType**

Comment: The same problem continues, there seems to be no time to upload, as small files work and larger ones don't

Comment: then check for limit/policies in S3 bucket setting, that can help

Comment: Thanks for the help, but there was no policy setting a limit either. I solved it as follows by changing it to upload using multerS3 directly from the backend so it uploads normally and I can limit the size of the files in the multer configuration.